# rails uploading a cropped image (canvas) on background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm developing on Rails and my app is on heroku.

I'm using `cropper.js` and carrierwave to let users select, crop, and upload an image to s3.
The step to post is really similar to Instagram.

I know there is [a way to directly upload an image to s3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails), but when using with `cropper.js`, this way doesn't work on some browsers.

Then I've decided to work with carrierwave, however, this really takes a lot of time to upload because of indirect uploading.

In order to shorten this time, I want to make uploading work on background. I know the existence of carrierwave-direct or carrierwave-backgrounder, but I don't think they work well with heroku or cropped image which is canvas.

Currently, my code is like following;

Does anyone know how to make these transaction work background and let users move to next page without waiting for finishing uploading?

In my view,

```
<%= form_for @post, :url => { :controller => :posts, :action => :create } , :id => 'myform' } do |f|%>

  <div class="field" >
  <%= f.label("Item image") %>
  <%= f.file_field :image_name, accept: 'image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif', :id => "image" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :remote_image_url %>

  <div class="preview"><img id="crop_img" /></div>
  <div class="clear_float"></div>

  <%= f.hidden_field :designer_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <div class="clear_float"></div>

  <%= f.label("comment") %>
  <%= f.text_area :detail %>

  <%= f.submit("post", :id => '_submit', "data-disable-with" => "uploading...") %>
<% end %>
```

In my javascript,

```
  $('#_submit').on('click', function(){
   // get cropped image data
   var canvas = $('#crop_img').cropper('getCroppedCanvas');
   var canvas_data = canvas.toDataURL();
   $("#post_image_name").val(""); 
   $("#post_remote_image_url").val(canvas_data);
   $("#myform").submit();
});
```

And in my controller,

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
 ...
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    post = params.require(:post).permit(
      :designer_id,
      :image_name,
      :remote_image_url,
      :detail
    )
    post[:image_name]= post[:remote_image_url]
    post[:remote_image_url] = ""
    @post = Post.new(post)
    if @post.save
      ...
    end
  end

  ...
  end
```